# How to draw gradient and customize your splash screen in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to have a splash screen in our application and I got stuck Abit with the jetpack Compose design. So I want to have a background gradient, I am now using the image which does not fit well in the phone and want to center my logo and text in the middle of the screen how can I achieve that. Mostly centering since I have tried the gradient part and I have no success. Here is my code

Here is my background component

```
@Composable
fun BackgroundComponents(
    @DrawableRes backgroundDrawableRes: Int,
    contentDescription: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    painter: Painter,
    alignment: Alignment = Alignment.Center,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = backgroundDrawableRes),
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            modifier = modifier.matchParentSize()
        )
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painter,
                contentDescription = contentDescription,
                alignment = alignment
            )
        }
        Text(
            modifier =
            modifier.padding(top = 36.dp),
            text = "Hello and welcome to our app",
            color = (colorResource(id = R.color.white)),
            fontSize = 16.sp,
        )
    }
}
```

This is how I am calling it on the Screen

```
@Composable
fun Splash(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        BackgroundComponents(
            backgroundDrawableRes = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            painter = painterResource(id = coil.base.R.drawable.notification_bg)
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to push the icon and text in the middle and centered, also instead of using an image can I draw that gradient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the gradient to the parent `Box` as `background` modifier and then just apply the expected alignment to the composable inside the `Box`.

Something like:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(
            Brush.horizontalGradient(
                colors = listOf(
                    Color.Blue,
                    Teal200
                )
            )
        ),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {

    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.xx),
            contentDescription = "contentDescription",
        )

        Spacer(Modifier.height(36.dp))

        Text(
            text = "Hello and welcome to our app",
            color = White,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So mine is not working, is it how I have defined the Splash compose function.

Comment: I noticed what the issue was and it works like magic, Thank you